# Python - getting error with video link from youtube api request

Tags: python, selenium, attributes

This following code seems to be working for other elements-

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(".\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/c/edurekaIN/videos")
driver.implicitly_wait(180)

videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')

for video in videos:
    title = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
    views = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
    when = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
    print (title, views, when)
    print (driver.find_elements_by_id("thumbnail").get_attribute('href'))
```

I am getting title, views, when etc.
But getting error for the following-

```
print (driver.find_elements_by_id("thumbnail").get_attribute('href'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.......py", line 35, in <module>
    print (driver.find_elements_by_id("thumbnail").get_attribute('href'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The reason why you are not getting the href is, because your locator is incorrect. If you want to pick the first thumbnail, then use xpath: By.xpath("(.//*[@id='thumbnail'][1])[2]")).getAttribute("href").  If you need all, then loop from 2 to 32. Like this: By.xpath("(.//*[@id='thumbnail'][1])[" + j + "]")).getAttribute("href") where j will go from 2 to 31.

Comment: The url contains api and you can grab the desired data from api  without any  complexity. Create new  post or  modify it.